# A complete example of how to use xbmcgui.ControlSlider with actions

Tags: slider, kodi

Is it me or there is no example of how to use `xbmcgui.ControlSlider`?
I have this code:

```
    self.mediaPath=os.path.join(addon.getAddonInfo('path'),'resources','media') + '/'
    self.slider = xbmcgui.ControlSlider(19, 415, 1242, 130,self.mediaPath + 'tran.png',self.mediaPath + 'poser.png',self.mediaPath + 'poser.png')
    self.addControl(self.slider)
```

But I can't find how to detect slider actions.

Answer (score 0):

**class xbmcgui.ControlSlider**(x, y, width, height, textureback=None, texture=None, texturefocus=None, orientation=VERTICAL)

Bases: xbmcgui.Control

*ControlSlider class.*

Creates a slider.

Parameters:

- x – integer – x coordinate of control.
- y – integer – y coordinate of control.
- width – integer – width of control.
- height – integer – height of control.
- textureback – string – image filename.
- texture – string – image filename.
- texturefocus – string – image filename.
- orientation – int – orientation of the slider

**Notes:
By default a ControlSlider has vertical orientation.**

**After you create the control, you need to add it to the window with addControl().**

Example:

```
self.slider = xbmcgui.ControlSlider(100, 250, 350, 40)
```

**Methods:**

**getPercent()**

Returns a float of the percent of the slider.

Example:

```
self.slider = xbmcgui.ControlSlider(100, 250, 350, 40)
percent = self.slider.getPercent()
```

**setPercent(percent)**

Sets the percent of the slider.

Parameters: percent – float – slider % value

Example:

```
self.slider = xbmcgui.ControlSlider(100, 250, 350, 40)
percent = self.slider.setPercent(20)
```